# R - how to "insert" a value into a row for a fill-in matrix

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

### EDIT

Hello, here's a more reproducible example.

I have an R script that borrows heavily from this [blogpost](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/04/retirement-simulating-wealth-with-random-returns-inflation-and-withdrawals-shiny-web-application/) and I'm trying to make some modifications to how the matrix of each simulation is constructed.

I'm really bad with for-loops in R, so I need a little help figuring it out.

What I'm hoping to do is find a way to inject a value to (re-baseline) for a certain row (or rows) ... maybe I'm over thinking this and missing something obvious?

```
# starting cash for each "simulation"
principle = 100

#starting inflation assumption
inflation = .05

#starting returns
returns = .02

# number of time units (lets say months)
n.obs = 5

# number of simulations (columns)
n.sim = 5

# time I retire and get access to 401k
  t_retire = 4
    
# amount of money available to be added to my principal at t==t_retire
  retire = 100

# simulate cases - they're all the same in this example
nav = matrix(start.capital, n.obs + 1, n.sim)
for (j in 1:n.obs) {
  nav[j + 1, ] = (nav[j, ] * (1 + returns - inflation))
}
```

I want to edit this for-loop to add the "retire" value to my existing "principle" at row (t_retire) = 4.

Comment: You should lay out you plan for this simulation in natural language. For instance it appears that you are using row to represent "time" in months but you never actually express that intent. You also are not naming your columns and there are 1000 of them so it's not clear where you want to put all the starting values for you first code block that does initialization. AND you ask how to ""insert" this value into the matrix below at time (row) = retirement_months?", but you never say **which** value you are talking about. AND what does it mean to "call out the row number in this for-loop"?

Comment: Hi @IRTFM thanks for the note. You're right that row represents time in months. I mentioned that in the introductory paragraph, but could have commented the code. The "insert" value refers to `retirement_start_capital` and had that commented in the description.

Comment: If you want to  put a value in the first column in the 420th month, then why not `nav[ retirement_months, 1] <- retirement_start_capital`

Comment: How does that interact with the for loop though? 

For example,  how would I add ```[nav[j, ] + retirement_start_capital] * (1 + monthly.invest.returns[j, ]...``` for a single row in the matrix at time (row) 
 ```nav[retirement_months, ]``` ?

Comment: You mean the loop in the completely comment and documentation free section of code that comes next? Why don't you [edit] the question to be a [MCVE] noting that "M" stands for minimal, C means both "complete" and "commented".

Comment: Made a substantial update that's hopefully simpler @IRTFM thanks for your patience.

Comment: Much simpler. Really helps to be able to look at a full result. Hundreds of rows and ta thousend column is just not going to allow you to look at it. Better to start small and then scale up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the minimal example I think this might be what is desired:

```
 nav = matrix(start.capital, n.obs + 1, n.sim)

 for (j in 1:n.obs) { if(j==t_retire){nav[j, ] <- nav[j-1, ] + retire}
    nav[j + 1, ] = (nav[j, ] * (1 + returns - inflation))
 }
 nav
 #----------------------
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 100000.00 100000.00 100000.00 100000.00 100000.00
[2,]  97000.00  97000.00  97000.00  97000.00  97000.00
[3,]  94090.00  94090.00  94090.00  94090.00  94090.00
[4,]  94190.00  94190.00  94190.00  94190.00  94190.00
[5,]  91364.30  91364.30  91364.30  91364.30  91364.30
[6,]  88623.37  88623.37  88623.37  88623.37  88623.37
```

If it's not the desired modification then at least it may form the basis for clarification. Not that the R habit of filling rows with copies of single values is at work here.

Comment: Hrm, I think this is closer. I'm expecting row 4 to be 194090 (```94090``` from ```[3, ]``` plus ```100000``` from the 401k unlock ```retire```) > my question is, how do we add that value just to row 4 and continue the logic for the rest of the matrix?

Comment: Appears you want the row to be chosen on the basis of Not sure how you got `retire` to be 100000 since your new code defines it as 100, but I've [edit]-ed my answer. You need to learn the difference between "principal" and "principle".

Comment: Ah, sorry yeah that was a typo. And yes, this looks like expected results. Thanks so much for your patience here!

Comment: I think I actually have an edit on your code ... the loop should be ```for (j in 1:n.obs) { if(j==t_retire){nav[j, ] <- nav[j-1, ] + retire}
    nav[j + 1, ] = (nav[j, ] * (1 + returns - inflation))``` -> added a comma

Comment: Yep. Comma needed.